# how do i subscribe to activemq to get notified when message has been processed by consumer

Tags: jms, monitoring, activemq-classic

I'm actually looking for an advisory or any other alternative support from ActiveMQ, so that i could be notified when the MessageListener associated with a Consumer finishes processing the message.

The MessageDelivered advisory seems to notify as soon as the broker gets the message. Also, the MessageConsumed advisory claims to notify when a consumer receives the message.

------------------------UPDATE------------------------------

Please find the code snippet below:

```
public class SampleListener implements MessageListener {

    private Session session;

    public SampleListener(Session session) {
        this.session = session; 
    }

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
             // do something
             session.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class SampleConsumer {

    private boolean stopConnection = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SampleConsumer().start();
    }

    public void start() {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
            Connection connection;
            try {
                connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
                connection.start();
                Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
                Destination destination = session.createTopic("test");
                MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
                messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new SampleListener(session));

                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        while (!stopConnection) {
                            wait();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    session.close();
                    connection.close();
                }

            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        synchronized (this) {
            stopConnection = true;
            notify();
        }
    }
}


public class SampleProducer implements MessageListener {

    private boolean messageDelivered;

    @Test
    public void shouldTestSomething() throws JMSException, InterruptedException {
        producerConnection = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616").createConnection();
        producerConnection.start();
        Session session = producerConnection.createSession(true, SESSION_TRANSACTED);

        Destination destination = session.createTopic("test");
        MessageConsumer advisoryConsumer = session.createConsumer(AdvisorySupport.getMessageConsumedAdvisoryTopic(destination));
        advisoryConsumer.setMessageListener(this);

        Message message = session.createTextMessage("Hi");
        Destination destination = session.createTopic("test");
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        producer.send(message);
        session.commit();

        synchronized (this) {
            while (!messageDelivered) {
                wait();
            }
        }

        session.close();

        // some assertions
    }

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // do something

        synchronized (this) {
            messageDelivered = true;
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you set ack-mode as transacted, MessageConsumed advisory still happens early? According to closing reason of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3361 it shouldnt.

Comment: Aksel, the ack-mode is already transacted. While MessageDelivered advisory happened early, i couldn't get any notification with MessageConsumed advisory. I had the PolicyEntry parameter to switch on MessageConsumed, but still there wasn't any message enqueueing for the MessageConsumed advisory.

Comment: im not following. is the problem that you think message consumed will happen to early or that you dont manage to enable the advisory for it?

Comment: the latter. i do see MessageConsumed advisory enlisted in the Topics section of the admin console, but nothing happens to this Topic i.e the listener configured to listen to this advisory never gets invoked. Whereas, when listening to MessageDelivered advisory, notification happens before consumer finishes consuming the message.

Comment: You are invoking the session.commit() in onMessage() ? Otherwise im out of guesses and would prolly need to see some code to answer better

Comment: Yup, i do commit at the end. The consumer session is different from producer session though

Comment: Aksel, please find the code updated in the question

Answer (score 1):

Some of the advisories are not enabled by default. Se link:

http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html

Disabled Advisories can be enabled by adding a policyEntry to the activemq.xml 
http://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html

Add the following to activemq.xml:

```
     <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" advisoryForConsumed="true" />
            <policyEntry  queue=">" advisoryForConsumed="true" />
            ..            
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
```

After enabling the advisory and invoking session.commit() in the consumer the advisory would be delivered.

If you are using embedded broker you can just place activemq.xml on the classpath and start the broker using:

```
BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker("xbean:activemq.xml",true);
```

(I didnt find any way to enable disabled advisories without using activemq.xml).

Comment: Thanks Aksel. I've always been having advisoryForConsumed="true" in the policyEntry (I use an external broker, and not an embedded one). The admin console does show an entry for this advisory, and it does reflect the advisory message listener. But no advisory messages get enqueued in this advisory, and so no message reaches the listener.
My gut feel is that it has got to do with producer and consumer using different sessions, and being in different thread, but i can't figure out why that should be a problem.

Comment: i got your code to work with minor changes, sec and ill paste it

Comment: Guess im not gonna make you happy, one of the changes was using queue instead of topic: consumer: http://pastebin.com/sJUqrVTi producer: http://pastebin.com/XK0SGXnz config: http://pastebin.com/zpN850st

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for pointing out that it works with queues, i tried it and it worked too ! Fortunately, i now realize that the app i'm building would rather work on queue semantics, coz topic wouldn't buffer any message till a subscriber registers. So that should solve my problem.
But still i'm curious as to why MessageConsumed advisory wouldn't work for topics. Is it intentionally not functional? Or was i missing something?

Comment: is it possible to subscribe advisory topic in javascript using PAHO or other JS  client

Comment: AFAIK, the client in use wont affect advisory topics. But you would have to try. I never used JS client

Comment: I think that getting an advisory for message consumption on a topic may not make sense. The reason being that messages sent to a topic can be consumed by many consumers. There could potentially be many advisory notifications for the same message in this case. Having an advisory for messages sent to a queue does make sense because those messages can only be consumed by a single consumer.